# How to build and test application inside a Docker in GitLab CI?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, dockerfile

Our application has a `Dockerfile` that describes a custom image we'd like to use for to build and test application.

Basically, for every `git push` we want to:

1. Build an image from a Docker file.
2. Run a container based on this image.
3. Run build and tests in a container.
4. Get test results back to GitLab.

While it seems to be absolutely doable with GitLab CI's Shell Executor, I'm wondering if there is a recommended way to do such a thing?

Also, does this plan sounds appropriate for GitLab CI + Docker combination?